# PHP - Reference associative array inside same one

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to get the associate array inside the same associative array? For example:

```
<?php
$config = [
    'uri' => [
        'base_url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], // example.com
        'protocol' => 'https://',
        'url' => $config['uri']['protocol'] . $config['uri']['base_url'] // output: https://example.com
    ]
];
```

Obviously, that's not going to work but you get the idea. I've been looking at the PHP docs but I cannot find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an intermediate variable:

```
$base = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$protocol = 'https://';
$config = [
    'uri' => [
        'base_url' => $base, // example.com
        'protocol' => $protocol,
        'url' => $protocol.$base,
    ]
];
```

There's no reason to be afraid to use intermediate variables.

Comment: Why waste all that memory

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is readability not a good enough reason? It makes it easy to see what the config's `uri` section contains at a glance. If I saw that array declaration I would not expect more entries to be added to it later on.

Comment: @RiggsFolly With PHPs inbuilt opcode cache you're not really wasting memory (as I understand it, not intimately familiar with PHPs opcode cache internals)

Comment: you must be creating 2 addresses on the heap and load (x) bytes of data into the heap to contain the values. These 2 addresses and the data they point at are never used again in the program. _If thats not waste I dont know what is_ Add to that the well know over allocation of memory for the array to make PHP arrays so flexible. And all you do is move the data from one memory buffer to another i.e. the array

Comment: Riggs, I think you're blowing this way out of proportion. If the opcode cache doesn't optimise this (and I'm pretty sure it would), you would be adding a few _bytes_ to the execution of your script. Unlikely to make any difference. Saying this is a waste of memory is pretty overzealous.

Answer (score 2):

Not like you have done it, but you can do it in 2 steps like this

```
$config = [
    'uri' => [
        'base_url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], // example.com
        'protocol' => 'https://'
    ]
];

$config['uri']['url'] = $config['uri']['protocol'] . $config['uri']['base_url'];

print_r($config);
```